# Print statement not printing when zipped string is printed

Tags: python, printing, zlib

I have a python script that reads as follows:

```
import zlib;
print("hi")
print(str(zlib.compress('@echo alert`void f(){System.out.println("echo\"void f(){cout<<\\"\\\\"-[--->+<]>---.----[-->+++<]>.+[->+++<]>.+++.--[--->+<]>-.+++[->++<]>+.[--->+<]>++.---.--------.--.+++.+++++++++++++.-----------.\\\\"\\"}\""`')))


print("welp")
```

https://ideone.com/gJWnUU

As you can see, there is no output from this, from either the `print("hi")` or the zlib compression `print`.  The value I'm trying to compress I don't think is breaking it, seeing as the string itself seems to be valid.

What is causing this, and how do I fix it to get the compressed string?  (removing the other two `print` statements does nothing)

Comment: Try `print(repr(...))` because you may be printing a character that is screwing up your terminal.  Works on my machine.  Is this only a problem on that site (ideone.com)?  Or do you see the same behavior locally?

Comment: Confirmed, doesn't work on their site.  But this does: https://ideone.com/ypXUCQ

Comment: I was seeing this behavior locally as well.  Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Why having `;` at the end of a line? In Python it is not needed. Furthermore, in many similar questions with printing problems I have seen people using it, maybe it has something to do...